# Best way to measure how well stochastic models fits a system of differential equations?

Tags: simulation, differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations which can be easily solved using ode45 in matlab. The equations represent a biochemical pathway.

I have simulated the same biochemical pathway stochastically.

I want to create a cost function to measure how well the output of the stochastic biochemical simulation fits the differential equations which describe the same process.

Any advice? Apologies if my question seems unclear I am happy to clarify in the comments.

**More details as requested in the comments**

Used [smoldyn](http://www.smoldyn.org) to simulate the biochemical pathway. The output of this is a csv file with each row containing the number of particles of each type in the pathway and a column for time.

The system of ODEs can be seen [here](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1186%2Fs12964-016-0128-z/MediaObjects/12964_2016_128_MOESM2_ESM.pdf) solving these with ode45 in matlab will also produce a csv file with each row containing the number of particles at each time point.

Comment: Can you post the system of ODEs and whatever methods used to "simulate stochastically?"

Comment: @AlexR. thanks for the response Alex, the question has been updated.

Comment: For the ODEs, have you tried plugging the system into Mathematica to obtain an exact solution?

Usually the way to compare stochastic odes to their nonstochastic counterparts, is to measure the differences $|y_t-s_t|$, where $y_t$ is the non-stochastic solution and $s_t$ is the stochastic solution. For example you could compute the average distance (via some discretization of time) and compare it to the noise terms in your stochastic ODE, perhaps after resampling paths a few thousand times.